# How do I determine the newest file in a folder?

Tags: windows, ntfs

My office keeps all files for a given project in folders on a shared network drive.  When a project's files haven't changed for a few months, I archive the project folder to another shared network drive.

To assist with this process, I'm looking for a way to search for the newest file timestamp in a given folder (including its sub-folders.)  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either sort based on last created or modified in explorer, or use the following command in the command prompt:

```
dir /TW /O-D
```

Replace /TW with /TC if you want creation date instead of last written date

Edit: If you want to see all subfolders as well, you can add the `/S` switch to the command. If you want to pipe it to a text file, add (for example) `> files.txt` to save it to files.txt

Comment: +1 The ultimate free tool - one that comes with the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the last version of each file if you have a lot of different files for each project, you could use a free versioning software used usually by developpers like cvs, bazaar or git. This wouldn't be as simple as Hyppy asnwer but would keep track of versions of each file and would be easier to maintain a lot of different files.